# Removing new line from CSV file

Tags: regex, shell, unix, unoconv

I have a script that converts excel file into csv using unoconv. 
I noticed that some records in the csv is added as a new line due to particular format in excel. I was wondering if there is anyway this can be handled in unix.

sample problematic data.

```
col1, col2, col3
jim,"washington dc
",123
```

correct data should be.

```
col1, col2, col3
jim,"washington dc",123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `gnu sed`:

```
cat file
```

```
col1, col2, col3
jim,"washington dc
","12
3"
foo, bar, baz
123, abc, xyz
```

And `sed` command:

```
sed -E ':a;N;;s/(,"[^"]*)\n/\1/;$!ba' file
```

```
col1, col2, col3
jim,"washington dc","123"
foo, bar, baz
123, abc, xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are wring to the csv file use below `sed` command it will remove the `\n` character with a space:-

```
 modifiedline=$(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' $line) 
 echo -e "$modifiedline\n" >> csvfile.csv
```

It works for me. You have to modify your existing shell script where it wring into the `csv` file and add the above command to fix your issue.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I've tried it. what it did was combine all rows into 1.

Comment: @user2058738, I have modified my answer. I checked in my system. Its works. You have to modify your existing shell script where it wring into the file and add the above command to fix your issue.